# How to unload swf with GreenSock SWFLoader if the swf file has external class references?

Tags: flash, actionscript, gsap, swfloader

I try to load a swf file to show on the stage, if the swf file has no external class, i use 
swfLoader.unload();, then ide consoln "Unloaded: E:\Projects\TweenTest\bin\ui.swf", but if the ui.swf has some external class references , use unload method can't get this message, it means it's not be unloaded in nature; How can I unload it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LoaderMax can't know what dependencies your subloaded swf creates or clean up its references to external objects/classes/NetStreams - you need to do that before you unload() or dispose(true).